# How do I identify the corresponding position in a parallel array, if I know the index of the corresponding position in one array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a simple JavaScript program to calculate the winner of an election.
I use a FOR loop to assign the total of each candidates votes into a new array called totalVotesArray, I then output the corresponding candidates names and total votes into the browser window.

I then need to output the highest scoring candidate - I've used another FOR loop but I'm not sure I've done that part correctly. I'm stuck finding the index of the winning score and relating that the corresponding position in the parallel array.

Anyone know how I do this?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
Election Results
</TITLE>
<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="tma03.css">
<script type="text/javascript">

var candidateArray = ['Ms A  Brown .......', 
                      'Mr C Smith .......', 
                      'Ms F Patel .......', 
                      'Ms B Jones .......', 
                      'Mr E Williams...', 
                      'Mr D Johnson ....', 
                      'Ms G Taylor'];
var onlineVotesArray = [41,37,43,11,59,21,36];
var paperVotesArray = [22,3,15,11,7,1,18];


//initialises totalVotesArray with a new empty array the same size as candidateArray
var totalVotesArray = new Array(candidateArray.length)

//for loop counts the number of times the addition of the online and paper votes should be performed
for (var i = 0; i <= candidateArray.length; i = i + 1)
{
/*adds elements at the position in the onlineVotesArray Array to the element in the same position in the paperVotesArray Array, and stores result in corresponding position in the total votes array  */
    totalVotesArray[i] = onlineVotesArray[i] + paperVotesArray[i];
}
//outputs the election report heading and results to the browser document window
document.write('Eatanswill Historical Society By Election' + '<BR>' + 'Declaration of Results' + '<BR>' + '<BR>');
document.write(candidateArray[0] + totalVotesArray[0] + '<BR>');
document.write(candidateArray[1] + totalVotesArray[1] + '<BR>');
document.write(candidateArray[2] + totalVotesArray[2] + '<BR>');
document.write(candidateArray[3] + totalVotesArray[3] + '<BR>');
document.write(candidateArray[4] + totalVotesArray[4] + '<BR>');
document.write(candidateArray[5] + totalVotesArray[5] + '<BR>');
document.write(candidateArray[6] + totalVotesArray[6] + '<BR>');
//this outputs an extra line break
document.write('<BR>');


//debugger;
var maximumTotalVoteIndex = 0;

for (var count = 1; count < totalVotesArray.length; count = count + 1)
{
    if (totalVotesArray[count] > maximumTotalVoteIndex)
        {
            maximumTotalVoteIndex = totalVotesArray[count];
        }
}

document.write( **THIS IS THE BIT I'M STUCK WITH** + ' is declared the winner');
</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
var maximumTotalVoteIndex = 0;
    var maximumVote=totalVotesArray[0];

    for (var count = 1; count < totalVotesArray.length; count = count + 1)
    {
        if (totalVotesArray[count] > maximumVote)
            {
                maximumVote = totalVotesArray[count];
                maximumTotalVoteIndex = count;
            }
    }

    document.write("Highest scoring Candidate is "+candidateArray[maximumTotalVoteIndex]+"with votes"+maximumVote);
```

Comment: no since we consider maximumTotalVoteIndex as 0 we have to start the checking from index 1.

Answer (score 0):

> maximumTotalVoteIndex = totalVotesArray[count];
>   There is the main problem.

totalVotesArray[count] is the number of votes for the count-th person, whereas maximumTotalVoteIndex is the person.

So you should keep maximumTotalvoteIndex = count.

By the way, count should begins from 0 in your for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I was looking for an explanation so I know what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Typo on this loop, should be `<` not `<=` so;

```
//for loop counts the number of times the addition of the online and paper votes should be performed
for (var i = 0; i < candidateArray.length; i++)
```

Then the simplest way later on, given that you must account for **ties** is to;

```
//get max value;
var maximumTotalVoteValue = 0;
for (var count = 0; count < totalVotesArray.length; count++) {
    if (totalVotesArray[count] > maximumTotalVoteValue) {
        maximumTotalVoteValue = totalVotesArray[count];
    }
}

//find ppl with maximum vote
var winners= [];
for (var count = 0; count < totalVotesArray.length; count++) {
    if (totalVotesArray[count] === maximumTotalVoteValue) {
        winners.push(candidateArray[count]);
    }
}

//show results
if (winners.length === 1) {
    document.write(winners[0] + " is declared the winner");
} else {
    document.write(" Tied: " + winners.join(" and "));
}

document.write(", with: " + maximumTotalVoteValue );
```

Comment: thanks Alex - I didn't even consider ties! thank you for your detailed answer